# SQL combining multiple tables then combining duplicates

Tags: sql

Couldn't find any other questions & answers relating to this, so hoping for some help:

I have the below code:

```
SELECT V.vend_id, P.prod_id, OI.quantity, OI.item_price, OI.quantity*OI.item_price AS total
FROM vendors as V
JOIN products as P
    ON V.vend_id = P.vend_id
JOIN orderitems as OI
    ON OI.prod_id = P.prod_id
ORDER BY P.prod_id
```

Which brings up the below table:

[table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFg5h.png)

Is there anyway to combine the prod_id columns and sum the quantity for each prod_id relating to each vend_id like the below?

[table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFg5h.png)

Sorry if the current code is rubbish.....still an early learner for SQL!!

Thanks!

Comment: Please do not show your sample data as images, but as text. You are blocking people from reading this and make it harder for us to help you. Please read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: And please always tag SQL questions with the DBMS you are using. Which one is it? Oracle? MySQL? SQL Server? ...

Comment: Both links lead to the same image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below -

```
SELECT V.vend_id, P.prod_id, sum(OI.quantity) as qty, 
       sum(OI.item_price) price, sum(OI.quantity*OI.item_price) AS total
FROM vendors as V
JOIN products as P
    ON V.vend_id = P.vend_id
JOIN orderitems as OI
    ON OI.prod_id = P.prod_id
group by V.vend_id, P.prod_id
```